# Understanding how PDO / Prepared Statements work with multiple databases types

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, prepared-statement

I have only recently started working with `PDO` and `Prepared Statements` and understand how they work fine, however am now wanting to support multiple databases and have a few questions on how they work.

As I understand it if you use PDO within PHP then it will support many different database types out of the box; however I want to understand how this works.

For example, if I do this:

```
$data = array( 'name' => 'Cathy', 'addr' => '123 fake st', 'city' => 'fakesville' );

$sql = $db->("INSERT INTO folks (name, addr, city) value (:name, :addr, :city)");
$sql->execute($data);
```

I understand that will work on whatever database you want as long as it's supported?

If so, how does that work? Like does it turn the SQL statement into the corresponding syntax for each database engine itself?

If the above is true, is there anything I should be aware of that isn't supported? I think I read that you shouldn't use database specific functions?

If that is true, how do you go about doing that if you need to? Do you need to write the SQL for each database you want to support with their respective functions?

Commonly used ones would obviously be `COUNT` and `SUM` in MySQL; which would be the database language I would mainly be writing for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO is really just the connection driver to the database - meaning that it is a function that will support passing a SQL statement, preparing a statement, binding params, returning a recordset etc to many different database types - rather than having a single driver for each database vendor.

It won't change your SQL in any way, and if you have a statement that is only supported by a single database type, or a function in your query that is supported by one database engine and not another - the query will fail if passed to the wrong database.

The vast majority of queries will work on pretty much any SQL database, as the language has a standard written for it and most databases follow that standard - however, as your SQL grows more familiar with a particular DB engine you may find that it becomes less transferable to other engines.

If you are writing a query for a specific database, you can use all the tricks that db engine has to offer, but if you want your code to function on any of the PDO supported databases, you might have to write some more "vanilla" queries - even if they are slightly longer.

Edit: The best way to ensure that your code will be supported on multiple databases is to simply write "simple" or "plain" queries. When you get familiar with a particular database, you generally know what tricks each one has up its sleeves - and you know that, that particular trick is only in that database. For example, mySQL has a `group_concat()` function that won't work in any other database, oracle has many functions that work only on an Oracle database.

However, for the most part, a query written with a normal select, almost any aggregate functions, normal (left, right, inner) joins will work perfectly on each engine. You can also use one of the many websites (such as http://sqlfiddle.com/) to check what engines a query will work in or check http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: So what is the best way to go about making sure your code supports other databases rather than "hoping" it will? Do you need to use something like `Doctrine`? ...can't really just be done with the aforementioned?

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the tips. I was mainly worried about the usage of `JOINS`, `Sub-Selects`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING` and db functions. Thanks for the tip about sqlfiddle as well.

Comment: If you are worried about a particular feature - the simplest way is to enter in the name of the function you want to use along with the database engine (for example "oracle group_concat") into google and see what comes back. It's normally the fancy stuff that won't work - while all the normal run of the mill queries will work 100%.